# How to implement Flask-RBAC for mongoengine Document?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, rbac, flask-mongoengine

I have an existing project where I have built my models with mongoengine Documents. Now I want to implement role based access control in my project. I want to use [flask-rbac](https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with my User model, which currently looks like this:

```
class User(Document):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=Generator.generate_uuid)
    name = StringField(min_length=1, max_length=100, required=True)
    phone_number = StringField(min_length=10, max_length=15, required=True,
                               unique=True, validation=validate_phone_number)
    password = StringField(required=True)
```

As you can see, my model User is made by inheriting Document class. But from the documents of flask-RBAC, they are using `db.Model`. I am finding it hard how to incorporate RBAC by following the documentation, or maybe I am missing a very easy thing. Can anyone help me with this?

I want to implement two roles, admin and normal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question, I'll try to outline something here.

The `flask-rback` [documentation](https://flask-rbac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#set-role-model) where they use `db.Model` states that "*However, if your application is working under SQLAlchemy, and you want to save the roles in database, you need to override the Role class to adapt your application*". In the example, the db connection is probably done using, e.g., `flask-sqlalchemy` as described in this [minimal example](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application). However, pure `flask-sqlalchemy` does not work with MongoDb.

As you are using [Mongoengine](http://mongoengine.org/), it has an extension [Flask-MongoEngine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/projects/flask-mongoengine/en/latest/index.html). Using that you can handle the connection to your app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
db = MongoEngine(app)
```

Then you could probably follow the flask-rback documentation and declare you `Role` and `User` models

```
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    # columns
```

and instead of `db.relationship` in the example use the [`ReferenceField`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=referencefield#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) of Mongoengine.

I could not infer all the details from your question, but I hope this helps you forward with you app!

Cheers!